# Estimating sample size given its smallest member

Tags: probability, cryptography

I have a friend who has a list of `n` numbers from `[0, x)`. They are integers (though x is so large that doesn't really matter), and are uniformly randomly distributed. My friend figures out the smallest member from this set, and calls it `y`.

I know `x` and `y`, but not the original list of numbers or `n`. How can I estimate `n`? How accurate will my estimate be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias of any estimator will go to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. This is because as $n\to\infty$, the probability that $y=0$ goes to $1$. You have to assign some arbitrary estimate $n_0$ to $y=0$, and then no matter what estimates you assign to the other values of $y$, as $n\to\infty$ the expected value of your estimate will go to $n_0$ as $n\to\infty$, whereas it should be going to $\infty$ along with $n$.

However, you can estimate $1/(n+1)$. This is messy and approximate for a discrete distribution, so I'll derive it for a uniform continuous distribution on $[0,1]$ and you can use it as an approximation for your discrete case.

The cumulative distribution function for $y$ in this case is $1-(1-y)^n$, the density is $n(1-y)^{n-1}$, and the expected value of $y$ is

$$
\int_0^1n(1-y)^{n-1}y\,\mathrm dy=\frac1{n+1}\;.
$$

Thus $y$ is a unbiased estimator for $1/(n+1)$. Its variance is

$$
\begin{align}
\langle y^2\rangle-\langle y\rangle^2
&=
\int_0^1n(1-y)^{n-1}y^2\,\mathrm dy-\frac1{(n+1)^2}
\\
&=
\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}
\\
&=
\frac n{(n+1)^2(n+2)}
\\
&\sim\frac1{(n+1)^2}\;.
\end{align}
$$

Thus for large $n$ the standard deviation is also approximately $1/(n+1)$.

In the continuous case, you could use $n=y^{-1}-1$ to estimate $n$. The expected value of this estimator is infinite, but at least you'd have the right expected value for $1/(n+1)$. In the discrete case, you can't do this, since typically $y=0$ and then $y^{-1}$ isn't defined.

Comment: What do the angle brackets around `y` mean? By `y^-1`, you mean `1/y`, right?

Comment: @Nick: The angled brackets denote the expected value, otherwise also denoted by $E(y^2)$ or $\overline{y^2}$. Yes, $y^{-1}$ is standard notation for $1/y$.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your answer, but thank you.

Comment: @Nick: Feel free to ask about any parts you're not sure about.